# Can I overload a function based on the argument being a lvalue or a rvalue?

Tags: c++

In my template "smart pointer" class, I want to have separate constructors and assignment operators that take as arguments, respectively, lvalue and rvalue pointers. How should I write the functions?

Comment: What's a "constructor for a pointer", never mind the lvalue/rvalue part? Can you give an example?

Comment: @GregHewgill: Sounds like he's talking about the pointer being an argument.

Comment: trying to make a smart pointer that can point to an lvalue

Comment: *a smart pointer-to-pointer actually

Comment: since not all rvalues can be deleted, this plan failed, but I have found a much simpler, but still convenient solution:
template<class T, bool autorelease>
class PointerPtr;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 it's really easy, because an overload accepting an rvalue reference doesn't take precedence over one accepting an lvalue reference, but rvalues and only rvalues may bind to the former:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

void f(int*&) {
   cout << "lvalue_ptr ";
}

void f(int*&&) {
   cout << "rvalue_ptr ";
}

int* get_rvalue_ptr() {
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   int* ptr1;
   f(ptr1);
   f(get_rvalue_ptr());
}

// Output: lvalue_ptr rvalue_ptr
```

(Obviously the above overload constructions can be applied to your member functions, too.)

I'm not sure how you'd go about it in C++03, though. I think Boost has `is_rvalue` that you could play with in template parameters.